# Designing a RE to filter words

Tags: python, regex

I have used the following RE to filter text:

```
 reg_ex=re.compile(r"\breal[?]*|\breally\s*[?]+", re.IGNORECASE)
```

and following function:

```
def is_present(text):
    if reg_ex.search(text):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

the function outputs the following words as true:

```
1)real 
2)realization
3)this is not really true.
4)this is not real.
5)is this real?
6)really??????
7)really??!!!
8)really
```

but i dont want the RE to filter the word :
2) realization
as true

How should i change my RE?

Comment: it's hard to suggest a good solution without input sample and final expected output. Would you fix that?

Comment: _"i dont want the RE to filter the word : 2) realization"_ Well, __why__ not? If the only requirement is "don't match the word _realization_", then `(?!realization)\breal[?]|\breally\s[?]+` is a valid solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You must analyze your own regex before coming up with a solution. `\breal[?]*|\breally\s*[?]+` contains 2 alternatives, `\breal[?]*` and `\breally\s*[?]+`. `\breal[?]*` matches a word boundary (there may be a non-word char, or start of the string before the current location), then a substring `real`, and then 0 or more `?` symbols. The `\breally\s*[?]+` matches a word boundary, `really`, 0 or more whitespaces and **1** or more `?` symbols.It means, `realization` will match because the first alternative matches it flawlessly (word boundary, `real`, and 0 question marks after, the second alternative is not even tried).

The solutions are manifold, but here are some hints:

1) (the one that follows the original logic most) Add a negative lookahead `(?!ization)` after `real`: [`\breal(?!ization)[?]*|\breally\s*[?]+`](https://regex101.com/r/zYRPHY/1)

2) (following the logic...) You seem to allow any word that starts with `real`, use [`\breal(?!ization)`](https://regex101.com/r/zYRPHY/2/)

3) And if you are after just matching `real` or `really` as whole words, you may use [`\breal(?:ly)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/zYRPHY/3).

Answer (score 2):

I would use word boundary on both ends and use a group for words:

what about this?

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"\b(real|really)\b",re.IGNORECASE)
for i in ["really ???", "is this real?","realization"]:
    print(i,bool(r.search(i)))
```

output

```
really ??? True
is this real? True
realization False
```

the regex can even adapt to any list of words like this:

```
r"\b({})\b".format("|".join(["real","really"]))
```